# MongoDb Queries stop running with flushes set to 1

Tags: mongodb, go, cron

I am working on a project made in golang, and I have used mongoDb as database in the project.
I am working on the cron in the project, in which i have to process data to send reminders,
During the load testing of the cron, I have found some issues in the Db performance.

I have noticed that mongoDb stop working for sometime while executing queries, and i have noticed that issue after a certain interval of time,
e.g db stop working after every 1-2 minutes, and it again starts execution after 40-60 seconds.

To find the issue I have checked mongostat using cmd

> mongostat -u username --authenticationDatabase admin

In this I have found that mongoDb stops whenever the flushes set to 1, and it again starts execution after a certain time.
Can you please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: We don't know anything about your Go app neither your database structure (collections, indices, queries). It's unlikely that anyone can help you based on the data provided in the question.